# Countdown timer, trouble with setDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, countdowntimer

I am currently using a countdown timer through a library, to be specific - `flipclockjs`. Now I can get it to work and countdown properly when using intervals, but when trying to use `setDate` or such, I keep failing and it won't work at all.

I apologize if this is a nooby question, relatively new to these kinds of things still. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../compiled/flipclock.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../compiled/flipclock.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="clock" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var clock;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var clock;
        clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
            clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
            autoStart: false,
            callbacks: {
                stop: function() {
                    $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
                }
            }
        });

        clock.setTime(220880);
        clock.setCountdown(true);
        clock.start();
    });
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: There may not be any method like setDate available on clock object. Please check your browser console for the error.

Comment: If you see the documentation of FlipClock.js, clock returns FlipClock object. And it doesn't allow you to use the method setDate()

Answer (score 1):

You can initiate a date and then get the difference in seconds from that date and the current date and then initiate the FlipClock passing the diff value.

`var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock( diff ,{...});`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var d = new Date();
      d.setDate(d.getDate()+2);
      var curd = new Date();
      var diff = (d.getTime() - curd.getTime()) / 1000; //divide by 1000 to transform miliseconds in seconds
  
      var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff,{
          clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
          autoStart: true,
          countdown: true,
          callbacks: {
              stop: function() {
                  $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
              }
          }
      });
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.css">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="clock" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>
</body>
```